# Palindrome is Not wokring

Tags: java, stack, palindrome

```
import java.util.*;

public class FindingPalindrome {

    private String inputString;
    private Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

    public FindingPalindrome(String str)
    {
        inputString = str;
        fillStack();
    }

    public void fillStack()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++)
        {
            stack.push(inputString.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    public String reverseString()
    {
        String result = new String();
        while(!stack.isEmpty())
        {
            result = result.concat(Character.toString(stack.pop()));
        }

        return result;
    }

    public boolean isPalindrome()
    {
        if(inputString.equalsIgnoreCase(reverseString()))
                return true;

                else return false;
    }
}




public class TestPalindrome {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        String inputString  ="Straw? No, too stupid a fad. I put soot on warts";

        String inputString1 = inputString.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]","");
        FindingPalindrome p = new FindingPalindrome(inputString );

        if(p.isPalindrome())System.out.println("Is palindrome!");
        else System.out.println("Is not palindrome!");
    }

}
```

The above is the code that test Palindrome by Stack. Every thing runs fine, but the palindrome output is incorrect

Comment: i think its counting space as character

Answer (score 2):

You're constructing the `FindingPalindrome` object with `inputString`, while you should do it with `inputString1`:

```
FindingPalindrome p = new FindingPalindrome(inputString1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't make your question clear. Do you *need* to do this using a stack? It's incredibly simple otherwise (I don't know how to read your current algorithm):

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {

    StringBuffer reverseString = new StringBuffer();

    // reverse the string
    for (int i = s.length() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        reverseString.append(s.charAt(i));
    }
    return reverseString.toString().equals(s);
}
```

Your import would be:

```
import java.lang.StringBuffer;
```

I realize this answer won't help you if your intention is to maintain your current algorithm, but I thought I should offer up something like this anyways.

---

Some extra note: the [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) class has [`.reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#reverse()) which reverses the character sequence. In that case, you could use this instead of the above:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    return new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString().equals(s);
}
```

Comment: @mike: You need not import java.lang.StringBuffer as it is in the lang package which gets imported automatically.

Comment: @AwfullyAwesome: That's right but I feel like import statements should be included regardless. Doesn't make a difference in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If its just Palindrome check that you care about then here's a neat implementation:

```
public class Palindrome {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Some String";
    String reverse = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString();

    if (reverse.equals(input))
        System.out.println("String is strictly Palindrome.");

    else if (reverse.equalsIgnoreCase(input))
        System.out.println("String is Palindrome.");

    else
        System.out.println("String is not Palindrome.");
}
}
```

Comment: i thank you for the code, but for some reason my professor wanted to use Stack